# How to override R's paste() to add string sanitization against XSS javascript injection?

Tags: r, security

How do you override a function like paste() to add new behavior like sanitization in R?

Comment: Write your own function. If you name it `paste` it will "mask" the built-in `paste` and be used instead--not sure if that's what you mean by "override".

Comment: @GregorThomas I use python normally, I was more wondering about the technical parts like passing *args and **kwargs (in python) to the daughter function. I see that in R it is ... (ellipsis) I guess it was an easy question but the answer actually helped learn stuff I need to know :D

Comment: I'm glad you got the help you need--it just seems like if that's what you wanted to know your question title is a bit misleading. There's nothing about XSS javascript injection or the security tag that's really pertinent to the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make your own function, if your function is on the search path it will supersede the base function for example

```
## where is paste ?
getAnywhere("paste")

paste <- function(...){
  cat("I can  intercept base::paste here")
  base::paste(...)
}
## where is paste ?
getAnywhere("paste")

# using my paste
paste("look","here")
```

Comment: Would the list inside ... behave exactly like the real arguments would?
For instance, if ... is 5, 4, 7, would calling paste on ... behave the same?